# Oracle - Como forçar um tamanho de campo em um retorno de function

Tags: oracle, oracle11c

Espero ser claro nesta questão , vou definir de forma genérica mas creio que basta

1) Crio uma FUNCTION qualquer que retorne um VARCHAR , não inporta muito o que se retorna

2) Crio uma VIEW que usa esta FUNCTION

Resultado : A tamanho do campo que usa a FUNCTION na VIEW fica como VARCHAR(4000)

Pergunta : Existe alguma forma , na FUNCTION que posso especificar o tamanho do retorno ?

Exemplo de Códigos :

```
create or replace FUNCTION EXEMPLO ( pX IN VARCHAR2)

  RETURN  VARCHAR2 IS

  vSAIDA  VARCHAR2(6);
BEGIN

    --FAZ ALGUMA COISA E OBTEM VSAIDA;

END IF;

    RETURN vSAIDA;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RETURN ' ';
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_EXEMPLO
AS
SELECT EXEMPLO('1') SAIDA FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: você quer especificar o tamanho do retorno na function ou na view?

Comment: Grato pelo comentário. Queria que na VIEW fique com um tamanho específico , poderia fazer um CAST no SELECT da VIEW , mas quero saber se tem como definir ests saída na FUNCTION.

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente em funções definidas pelo usuário não é possível especificar o tamanho de retorno do `VARCHAR2`.

Como você mesmo observou, mesmo garantido que a função nunca retorne um `VARCHAR2` maior do que `6`, o tipo do retorno será `VARCHAR2(4000)` (ou `32767` caso você habilite [strings estendidas no Oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#r2c1-t3)).

Na grande maioria dos casos isso não faz tanta diferença uma vez que o espaço utilizado para armazenar uma string de tamanho variável independe do tamanho especificado no tipo (e.g., `'SALADA'` ocupa o mesmo espaço como `VARCHAR2(10)` do que ocuparia como `VARCHAR2(255)`).

Dito isso, por questões de [corretude](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corretude_(l%C3%B3gica)) e para casos em que a definição do tipo é importante para garantir a forma de entradas futuras (e.g., em um comando do tipo [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php)) sempre é possível fazer um `CAST` do retorno da função:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_EXEMPLO
AS
SELECT CAST(EXEMPLO('1') AS VARCHAR2(6)) SAIDA FROM DUAL;
```

---

**Fonte**: [DbaSpot - How to set the size of string returned by PL/SQL functions?](http://dbaspot.com/oracle-server/268838-how-set-size-string-returned-pl-sql-functions.html)

Comment: Grato @Anthony Accioly , vou seguir usando o CAST.

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, para especificar o tamanho de um retorno você pode simplesmente desfrutar das funções [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm) e [LPAD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm) ou [RPAD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions140.htm).

Exemplo: 
`return SUBSTR(LPAD('1', 6, '0'), 0, 6);`

Supondo que seu retorno tenha que ser exatamente de 6 caracteres, esta instrução usando a **LPAD** vai preencher o lado esquerdo do retorno com 0 até que ele tenha o length igual a 6, caso o length seja maior que 6, usando a **SUBSTR** ela delimitará o length até 6, descartando o restante.

Ficou claro? espero ter ajudado.

Comment: grato pela resposta. Já havia tentado isto mas quando chamo a FUNCTION via SELECT o type (ao menos no SQLDEVELOPER) , não sei se existe algum V$PARAMETER ou opção no SQLDEVELOPER.